# How to filter a JSON query using route parameters in AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I am trying to do this and cannot seem to figure it out.

I am using **resource** to consume a rest API like so:

```
.factory('Professor', [
  '$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/professors/:id', {
      id: '@id'
    });
  }
]);
```

This gets me JSON in the form:

```
[
  {
    'id' : 1,
    'name' : 'John Doe',
    'slug' : 'john-doe',  
  },
  {
    'id' : 2,
    'name' : 'Jane Austin',
    'slug' : 'jane-austin', 
  }
]
```

My **routes** are like this

```
.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/professor/:professor_id/:professor_slug', {
        controller : 'ProfessorDetailController',
        templateUrl : 'static/templates/partials/professor_detail.html'
      })
      .otherwise({ redirectTo : '/' });
  }
]);
```

My **controller** looks like this

```
.controller('ProfessorDetailController', [
    '$scope', '$routeParams', 'Professor', 
    function($scope, $routeParams, Professor) {
      $scope.professor_id = $routeParams.professor_id;
      $scope.professor_slug = $routeParams.professor_slug;
      $scope.professors = Professor.query();
    }
]);
```

Now lets say the user goes to the following url:

> www.mysite.com/#/professor/2/jane-austin

I want to filter the query in my controller to only contain Jane's information. Now I am not sure if this filtering should be done in templates or the controller, but either way I cannot figure it out. Any help on how to do this?

Note, both the slug field and the id field must match with the route parameters. The id is unique obviously.

Comment: [array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) could help doing it in the controller.

Comment: @ste2425 Can you elaborate on that please?

Comment: Why don't you filter it in the db directly, by using an other query with parameters?

Comment: what is the point of having the `@id` in the $resource if it doesn't send back associated data only? Doesn't seem your api is set up properly

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS has built-in filter named $filter that can be used to reduce array based on some condition,we have to inject it as $filter. Using this filter, you can specify condition by attributes or by text so your controller should be like this.

```
.controller('ProfessorDetailController', [
    '$scope','$filter', '$routeParams', 'Professor', 
    function($scope,$filter, $routeParams, Professor) {
      $scope.professor_id = $routeParams.professor_id;
      $scope.professor_slug = $routeParams.professor_slug;
      $scope.professors = Professor.query();
      $scope.filteredProfByText = $filter('filter')($scope.professors, 'jean'); // by text, it will check inside name and gender
      $scope.filteredProfByName = $filter('filter')($scope.professors, {name : 'Jane Austin'}); // by attribute
    }
]);
```

Comment: If its just an array the native `array.filter` would be better and probably faster.